# Clojure: destructure and rename with {:keys [...]}

Tags: clojure

Is it possible to both destructure and rename keys in one go?

Consider this:

```clj
(let [{:keys [response]} {:response 1}]
  (println response))
```

However, if I want to instead refer to `1` as `my-response`, I have to do something like:

```clj
(let [{:keys [my-response]} (clojure.set/rename-keys {:response 1} {:response :my-response})]
  (println my-response))
```

Obviously this does not work with `defn` destructuring.

Is there any way in Clojure to both destructure and rename keys?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use destructuring without `:keys`:

```
(let [{my-response :response} {:response 1}]
  (println my-response))
```

`{:keys [response]}` is syntactic sugar for `{response :response}`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
(let [{:keys [response]} {:response 1}
      my-response response]
   (println my-response))
```

For a better answer refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/57592661/2757027.

This answer is much closer to the question, but technically not single step. but this doesn't involve any complicated de-structuring.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a library, a more powerful destructuring tool is available from `tupelo.core/destruct`.  Here is an example:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(dotest
  (let [info  {:a 777
               :b [2 3 4]}
        mania [{:a 11} {:b 22} {:c [7 8 9]}]]
    (let [z ::dummy]
      (destruct [info {:a z
                       :b [d e f]}
                 mania [{:a ?} BBB {:c clutter}]]
        (is= z 777)
        (is= [d e f] [2 3 4])
        (is= a 11)
        (is= BBB {:b 22})
        (is= clutter [7 8 9])))))
```

So you can see that inside the `destruct` expression, the symbols `z`, `d`, `e`, `f`, `BBB`, and `clutter` are given the corresponding values from the input variables `info` and `mania`.  The special symbol `?` is interpreted to mean that the keyword `:a` creates a symbol `a` to receive the value `11`.